# How could I convert a mixed syntax list (ranges, etc) into a single list?

Tags: python, string, list

I couldn't think of a decent title, and I'm sorry for that. I've got an input I want to take from the user that allows a format like this (as a string):

```
1, 2,4, 9-13, 12, 3
```

And provides me with a list of integers like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

I can think of a few horrible ways to crack this, I just wonder if there's anything "nice". I'm submitting my first idea as an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is my "manual" way of doing this. It could do with checking for silliness like: `-------1` but it'll work if used properly.

```
import re
inp = '1, 2,4, 9-13, 12, 3'
ret = []

for g in re.sub(r'[^\d,\-]', '', inp).split(','):
    m = re.match('(-?\d+)-(-?\d+)', g)

    if not m:
        ret.append(int(g))
        continue

    # we're talking about a range.
    a, b = sorted([int(x) for x in m.groups()])
    ret += range(a, b+1)

#de-dupe
ret = list(set(ret))
```

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary You're completely correct. In a previous iteration I was adding one to the upper bound but that got lost on the cutting floor. **Edit:** Fixed.

Comment: If this works the way you want it to, I actually don't think it's too bad. One minor point: `sorted` takes an iterable, so you can leave off the square brackets (unless using Python earlier than 2.4).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
from itertools import chain

def solve(s):
    for x in s.split(','):
        #Strip the trailing and leading spaces + '-' and then split at '-' only once.
        d = x.strip(' -').split('-', 1) 
        if len(d) == 1:
            yield [int(d[0])]
        elif len(d) == 2:
            s, e = sorted(map(int, d))
            yield range(s, e+1)


print sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(solve('1--1, 2,4, 9-13, 12, 3'))))
print sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(solve('1, 2,4, 9-14, 12, 3, ------14'))))
print sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(solve('1, 2,4, -----6-----,9-14, 12, 3'))))
print sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(solve('1, 2,4,11--11, -----6-----,9-14, 12, 3'))))
```

**Output:**

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[-11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: The yeilding into chain is nice but it currently doesn't cope too well with minus numbers. Consider the list: `2, 3, 1--1` (should output `-1, 0, 1, 2, 3`). The map-cast is fancier than my list comprehension too.

Comment: @Oli Okay, so something like `-----------2` is going to be considered as `-2` or `2`?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about purposefully broken syntax like that, but `1--1` should mean "one to minus one".

Comment: @Oli Please check the updated solution.(Used the `a, b = sorted(...)` thing from your solution)